# Activeworkbook.save Not Saving - No Error Code Running through

Tags: vba, save

I am in Excel 2016 and for whatever reason all of my macros that have been running for 10+ years will not save.  Specifically, Activeworkbook.save, Thisworkbook.save, any saveas type code will run through, but not actually save anything.

even the simplest macro:

```vb
sub test()
activeworkbook.save
end sub
```

macros will run through, but not save.  There are no debug errors or anything.  I am running on a virtual firm machine and there must be something missing in the Excel setup?  Any help would be greatly appreciated I have tried almost everything.  Additionally, other users on my team can run the code on the same system from the same workbook successfully so it is something with my setup.

Any insight would be amazing.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe they're not saving where you expect?  One line of code isn't much to go on though.

Comment: Thank you for the comment Tim - I was able to fix my issue.  I had an add in which was for whatever reason interacting with VBA / not letting the files save.  When I disabled an add in for Refinitiv (Thompson Reuters) the code magically works again!

Answer (score 0):

VBA was interacting with an add in for Refinitive (Thompson Reuters) when this add in was disabled the code works again!